# Pytorch: model weights cannot be Updated”

Tags: python, pytorch

Here is a simple example:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Net,self).__init__()
    A = Variable(torch.randn((1)), requires_grad=True)
    self.A = nn.Parameter(A)
    self.B = nn.Linear(2,2)
    self.register_parameter("Ablah",self.A)

  def forward(self,x):
    self.B.weight.data = self.B.weight * self.A
    return self.B(x)

net = Net()
input = torch.ones(2,2)
input.requires_grad_(True)
output = net(input)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
loss = torch.norm(output)
print(net.A)
loss.backward()
optim.step()
print(net.A)
```

I am trying to modify a PyTorch model's parameter **self.B** with another parameter **self.A** by using the code `self.B.weight.data = self.B.weight * self.A`, but it seems that **A** has no grad and it can not be updated.

It has confused me for a long time. Is there anything wrong?

Please give me some advice. Thank you!

Comment: Your code is quite confusing. What is the `forward` method meant to do? And when you say "I am trying to modify a PyTorch model's parameter" do you mean initialise it with a different weight or you want to be changing it yourself as you train?

Comment: @Nerveless_child Thanks for your comment. "modify a PyTorch model's parameter" means I want to change the weight of parameter **self.B** myself